# How to turn Stream<Map<Outcome, Long>> to Map<Outcome, Long>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I wanted to use Java Stream API to refactor this code:

```
for (Round round : dataStore.getRounds()) {
            Map<Outcome, Long> outcomes = round.getOutcomes()
                    .stream()
                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
}
```

getRounds returns a List of Round objects and every Round has a List of Outcome, where Outcome is an enum. I managed to get to this far:

```
Stream<Map<Outcome, Long>> out = dataStore.getRounds()
                .stream()
                .map(round -> round.getOutcomes()
                        .stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())));
```

I can't figure out what's missing to turn this into a Map<Outcome, Long>, I'm new to Java, and to the Stream API so I'm still learning it. Can you help me?

Comment: What do you want to make of the `Long` values that can be linked to the same `Outcome` value? Sum them?

Comment: I wanted to count them in each List<Outcome>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to count the number of occurrences of each `Outcome`, you should use `flatMap` instead of `map`:

```
Map<Outcome, Long> out =
    dataStore.getRounds()
             .stream()
             .flatMap(round -> round.getOutcomes().stream())
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), 
                                            Collectors.counting()));
```

`.flatMap(round -> round.getOutcomes().stream())` will give you a single `Stream<Outcome>` of all the `Outcome`s of all the `Round`s.